# Watching twitch HD stream uses 100% CPU on Firefox/Chrome

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, streaming

My laptop lags whenever I watch **twitch** stream on **720p or higher**, video stutters and the laptop become impossible to use until I exit the twitch page. Watching in **480p or less is fine**.

The laptop is doing fine watching YouTube 1080p without issues, browsing, photo editing in GIMP, writing documents in LibreOffice Write, and all daily tasks.

But the moment I open a twitch stream cpu usage jump from 10~20% to 100% !

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04 LTS ( Xfce 4.14 )

Laptop specs:

- intel celeron n3350
- 4gb ddr4
- 64gb ssd with 450/200 read/write speed

I did **enable forced hardware acceleration** in browser's settings but nothing changed.

any hints?

---

**Update:**

I figured out a way to watch streams **1080p60 LAG-Free** using **StreamLink** + **VLC**.

**CPU USAGE IS ALWAYS BELOW 20%**, so the issue was clearly **browser related**.

Installed **StreamLink** and **VLC**.

from command line terminal I run any stream using:

```
streamlink twitch.tv/XXXX best
```

and the commands open VLC with the best resolution the streamer is using.

you can use any available resolution you want, like:

```
streamlink twitch.tv/XXXX 1080p60
streamlink twitch.tv/XXXX 720p60
streamlink twitch.tv/XXXX 480p
.. etc
```

keep in mind there is **no chat** BUT you can open the chat in a popout window **ALONE** in the browser **WITHOUT stream playing in the browser** so no cpu resources is used.

To open the chat in popout open the browser and write the following url:

https://www.twitch.tv/popout/XXXX/chat?popout=

Change **XXXX** to the **streamer username**.

this will work for me for now, thanks

Comment: How are you connected, WiFi or wired?

Comment: tried both wifi and cable, same result.